# Attach aluminum tube securely to base without welding/soldering?

Tags: steel, aluminum, welding, soldering

How can I securely attach 4-ft x 1" aluminum tube to an aluminum base without having to solder/welding or glue? The aluminum base is 1/8" thick.

The tubes are open on both sides, but they can be closed. I can also drill, but I want to avoid welding.

Welding aluminum is much more expensive than the cost of the base and tube combined.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: tight fitting wooden dowel (or metal) inside the tube at bottom .... bolt through plate into dowel

Answer (score 5):

I would use an aluminum safety rail floor flange.

Something like this Hollaender 45-5 square floor flange:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Glue a large bolt or allthread rod into one end of the tube. I'd use some sort of epoxy resin or [low-temperature thermoplastic](https://www.amazon.co.uk/White-Polymorph-granules-350gm/dp/B0027IZC3S). It will be helpful to rig up some jig to hold the bolt in position while the glue sets.

Then you can drill the base and either tap the hole or use a washer and locknut on the underside (if application and space permit, otherwise add feet at corners to make space)

You could also tackle this the other way around, drill the base, countersink the hole, glue a nut into the tube and use a countersunk bolt through the base into the tube.

Ditto pilot-drilled wooden dowel, glue and large woodscrew or coachscrew depending on environmental factors and anticipated mechanical loading or abuse.

Four foot gives a lot of mechanical leverage. Don't expect this to be indestructible.

Comment: Your last sentence is critical in this question. Even a welded and heat treated 4' long tube of 1" diameter will be easily damaged. Not heat treated? Bend like a willow in the wind.